# "Вторым периодом принято называть указы..." - так возможно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Историю гонений на ранних христиан принято делить на три периода:
>
> 1. Первый период гонений. I век. При императоре Нероне и Домициане. Нерон обвинил христиан в чудовищном пожаре Рима, и с 64 до 68 года
>      христиан распинали на крестах, отдавали на съеденье зверям, обливали
>      смолой и зажигали во время народных гуляний. Жертвами этих гонений
>      в том числе стали и верховные апостолы – Пётр и Павел. При Домициане
>      гонения распространились и на провинции Римской Империи.
> 2. Второй период гонений. Конец I века – середина II. **Вторым периодом принято называть указы императора Траяна, Марка Аврелия и
>      Септимия Севера.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может лучше так: **Со вторым периодом принято связывать указы императора Траяна, Марка Аврелия и Септимия Севера.**

https://azbyka.ru/goneniya-na-hristian

2. Второй период гонений. Во второй период наиболее сильные гонения были от императоров Траяна, Марка Аврелия и Септимия Севера.

Answer (score 1):

Неудачное выражение. Можно было написать:

> "Второй период (или его начало) **связывают** (по времени) **с указами**..."

Answer (score 0):

Первый период: Нерон обвинил христиан в чудовищном пожаре Рима...

Второй период: стали издавать указы императора Траяна, Марка Аврелия и Септимия Севера.